# Streaming NSXMLParser with NSInputStream

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser, nsinputstream

**Update:**

When using `NSXMLParser` class method `initWithContentsOfURL`, rather than parsing as the XML feed is downloaded, it appears to try to load the entire XML file into memory, and only then initiate the parsing process. This is problematic if the XML feed is large (using an excessive amount of RAM, inherently inefficient because rather than parsing in parallel with the download, it only starts the parsing once the download is done, etc.).

Has anyone discovered how to parse as the feed is being streamed to the device using `NSXMLParser`? Yes, you can use `LibXML2` (as discussed below), but it seems like it should be possible to do it with `NSXMLParser`. But it's eluding me.

**Original question:**

I was wrestling with using [`NSXMLParser`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to read XML from a web stream. If you use [`initWithContentsOfURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLParser/initWithContentsOfURL%3a), while the interface may lead one to infer that it would stream the XML from the web, it doesn't seem to to do so, but rather appears to attempt to load the entire XML file first before any parsing taking place. For modest sized XML files that's fine, but for really large ones, that's problematic.

I have seen discussions of using `NSXMLParser` in conjunction with [`initWithStream`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLParser/initWithStream%3a) with some customized `NSInputStream` that is streaming from the web. For example, there have been answers to this that suggest using something like the `CFStreamCreateBoundPair` referred to in the [following Cocoa Builder post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/306924-asynchronous-downloading-and-parsing-of-xml.html) and the discussion of [Setting Up Socket Streams](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-BCIDFCDI) in the Apple *Stream Programming Guide*, but I have not gotten it to work. I even tried writing my own subclassed `NSInputStream` that used a [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (which is, itself, pretty good at streaming) but I wasn't able to get it to work in conjunction with `NSXMLParser`.

In the end, I decided to use [`LibXML2`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) rather than `NSXMLParser`, as demonstrated in the Apple [XMLPerformance sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html), but I was wondering if anyone had any luck getting streaming from a web source working with `NSXMLParser`. I've seen plenty of "theoretically you could do *x*" sort of answers, suggesting everything from `CFStreamCreateBoundPair` to grabbing the [`HTTPBodyStream`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLRequest/HTTPBodyStream) from [`NSURLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but I've yet to come across a working demonstration of streaming with `NSXMLParser`.

The Ray Wenderlich article [How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) seems to confirm that `NSXMLParser` is not well suited for large XML files, but with all of the posts about possible `NSXMLParser`-based work-arounds for streaming really large XML files, I'm surprised I have yet to find a working demonstration of this. Does anyone know of a functioning `NSXMLParser` implementation that streams from the web? Clearly, I can just stick with `LibXML2` or some other equivalent XML parser, but the notion of streaming with `NSXMLParser` seems tantilizingly close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-[NSXMLParser initWithStream:]` is the only interface to `NSXMLParser` that currently performs a streaming parse of the data. Hooking it up to an asynchronous `NSURLConnection` that's providing data incrementally is unwieldy because `NSXMLParser` takes a blocking, "pull"-based approach to reading from the `NSInputStream`. That is, `-[NSXMLParser parse]` does something like the following when dealing with an `NSInputStream`:

```
while (1) {
    NSInteger length = [stream read:buffer maxLength:maxLength];
    if (!length)
        break;

    // Parse data …
}
```

In order to incrementally provide data to this parser a custom `NSInputStream` subclass is needed that funnels data received by the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` calls on a background queue or runloop over to the `-read:maxLength:` call that `NSXMLParser` is waiting on.

A proof-of-concept implementation follows:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ReceivedDataStream : NSInputStream <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
@property (retain) NSURLConnection *connection;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *bufferedData;
@property (assign, getter=isFinished) BOOL finished;
@property (retain) dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;
@end

@implementation ReceivedDataStream

- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if (!(self = [super init]))
        return nil;

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    self.connection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO] autorelease];
    self.connection.delegateQueue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.bufferedData = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.connection = nil;
    self.bufferedData = nil;
    self.semaphore = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)hasBufferedData
{
    @synchronized (self) { return self.bufferedData.count > 0; }
}

#pragma mark - NSInputStream overrides

- (void)open
{
    NSLog(@"open");
    [self.connection start];
}

- (void)close
{
    NSLog(@"close");
    [self.connection cancel];
}

- (NSInteger)read:(uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxLength
{
    NSLog(@"read:%p maxLength:%ld", buffer, maxLength);
    if (self.isFinished && !self.hasBufferedData)
        return 0;

    if (!self.hasBufferedData)
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSAssert(self.isFinished || self.hasBufferedData, @"Was woken without new information");

    if (self.isFinished && !self.hasBufferedData)
        return 0;

    NSData *data = nil;
    @synchronized (self) {
        data = [[self.bufferedData[0] retain] autorelease];
        [self.bufferedData removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        if (data.length > maxLength) {
            NSData *remainingData = [NSData dataWithBytes:data.bytes + maxLength length:data.length - maxLength];
            [self.bufferedData insertObject:remainingData atIndex:0];
        }
    }

    NSUInteger copiedLength = MIN([data length], maxLength);
    memcpy(buffer, [data bytes], copiedLength);
    return copiedLength;
}


#pragma mark - NSURLConnetionDelegate methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"connection:%@ didReceiveData:…", connection);
    @synchronized (self) {
        [self.bufferedData addObject:data];
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading:%@", connection);
    self.finished = YES;
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore);
}

@end

@interface ParserDelegate : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
@end

@implementation ParserDelegate

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"parser:%@ didStartElement:%@ namespaceURI:%@ qualifiedName:%@ attributes:%@", parser, elementName, namespaceURI, qualifiedName, attributeDict);
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    NSLog(@"parserDidEndDocument:%@", parser);
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}

@end


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml"];
        ReceivedDataStream *stream = [[ReceivedDataStream alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithStream:stream];
        parser.delegate = [[[ParserDelegate alloc] init] autorelease];

        [parser performSelector:@selector(parse) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

        CFRunLoopRun();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I tried setting up a `NSURLConnection` as a stream (following the examples I referenced in my original question), I never got it to work. I see lots of posts and articles with hypothetical "well, you should be able to do X", but I never found a working example, and I never was able to get one working myself. Do you know of any working examples that marries `initWithStream` with `NSURLConnection`?

Comment: It seems like a an `NSURLConnection` delegate could feed the data it receives to an instance of an `NSInputStream` subclass. I'll throw something together to confirm it works.

Comment: It's not quite as easy as it first seems because `NSXMLParser` reads from the stream without spinning the runloop any, so you have to configure the `NSURLConnection` to send the delegate messages to a secondary thread or dispatch queue. Once that realization is made it is a simple matter of typing though :)

Comment: Oh, and I'd strongly suggest filing an enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com/ asking for a less cumbersome API for this.

Comment: First, thanks again for your help here. Second, there were a few minor issues with your above code sample, which I think I've remedied in my answer below. I'm going to leave your answer as "accepted", because you're the one that really solved the issue for me and pointed me in the right direction. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd suggest that proposing an edit to the answer would be less confusing.

Comment: Excellent. I'd therefore recommend an additional edit to this code to fix the semaphore bug. This code only works if `read:maxLength:` is _always_ waiting for a semaphore by the time that `didReceiveData` sends the semaphore. But if `didReceiveData` fills `bufferedData` and sends the semaphore before `read:maxLength:` calls `dispatch_semaphore_wait`, then `read:maxLength:` will not remove the semaphore and on the next call of `read:maxLength`, when it goes to wait for the semaphore, the previous signal is sitting there and this code then crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that bdash's answer used NSURLConnection. But according to the [NSURLConnection Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnection)

> This API is considered legacy. Use NSURLSession instead.

so I replaced it with NSURLSessionDataTask.

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/objc-sync.h>

@interface RemoteInputStream : NSInputStream
+ (instancetype)new NS_UNAVAILABLE;
+ (instancetype)inputStreamWithData:(NSData *)data NS_UNAVAILABLE;
+ (instancetype)inputStreamWithFileAtPath:(NSString *)path NS_UNAVAILABLE;
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data NS_UNAVAILABLE;
- (instancetype)initWithFileAtPath:(NSString *)path NS_UNAVAILABLE;

+ (instancetype)inputStreamWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;
- (instancetype)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end

@interface RemoteInputStream () <NSURLSessionDataDelegate>
@property (retain) NSURLSessionDataTask *sessionDataTask;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray<NSData *> *bufferData;
@property (retain, nullable) dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;
@end

@implementation RemoteInputStream

+ (instancetype)inputStreamWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    return [[[self.class alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];
}

- (instancetype)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    self = [self initWithRequest:request];
    [request release];
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    if (self = [super initWithURL:request.URL]) {
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *sessionDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
        self.sessionDataTask = sessionDataTask;
        
        NSMutableArray<NSData *> *bufferData = [NSMutableArray<NSData *> new];
        self.bufferData = bufferData;
        [bufferData release];
    }
    
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_sessionDataTask cancel];
    [_sessionDataTask release];
    [_bufferData release];
    
    if (_semaphore) {
        dispatch_release(_semaphore);
    }
    
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)open {
    self.sessionDataTask.delegate = self;
    [self.sessionDataTask resume];
}

- (void)close {
    [self.sessionDataTask suspend];
}

- (NSInteger)read:(uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)len {
    objc_sync_enter(self);
    
    if (self.bufferData.count == 0) {
        if (self.sessionDataTask.state == NSURLSessionTaskStateRunning) {
            dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
            self.semaphore = semaphore;
            
            objc_sync_exit(self);
            
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
            objc_sync_enter(self);
            
            self.semaphore = nil;
            dispatch_release(semaphore);
            
            if (self.bufferData.count == 0) {
                objc_sync_exit(self);
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            objc_sync_exit(self);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    NSMutableData *result = [NSMutableData new];
    NSUInteger remaining = len;
    
    while (YES) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
        
        BOOL shouldBreak;
        
        if (remaining < self.bufferData[0].length) {
            NSData *data1 = [self.bufferData[0] subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, remaining)];
            NSData *data2 = [self.bufferData[0] subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(remaining, self.bufferData[0].length - remaining)];
            
            [result appendData:data1];
            [self.bufferData replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:data2];
            remaining = 0;
            shouldBreak = YES;
        } else {
            [result appendData:self.bufferData[0]];
            remaining -= self.bufferData[0].length;
            [self.bufferData removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            
            if (self.bufferData.count == 0) {
                shouldBreak = YES;
            } else {
                shouldBreak = NO;
            }
        }
        
        [pool release];
        
        if (remaining == 0) {
            shouldBreak = YES;
        }
        
        if (shouldBreak) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    objc_sync_exit(self);
    
    NSUInteger length = result.length;
    
    memcpy(buffer, result.bytes, length);
    [result release];
    
    return length;
}

#pragma mark - NSURLSessionDataDelegate

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    objc_sync_enter(self);
    [self.bufferData addObject:data];
    
    if (self.semaphore) {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore);
    }
    
    objc_sync_exit(self);
}

@end
```

An example of unit test code:

```objectivec
#import <XCTest/XCTestCase.h>

@interface RemoteInputStreamTests : XCTestCase
@end

@implementation RemoteInputStreamTests

- (void)test_read {
    NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/11/2500/1667.jpg?hmac=xxjFJtAPgshYkysU_aqx2sZir-kIOjNR9vx0te7GycQ"];
    NSData *normalData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:testURL];
    
    RemoteInputStream *inputStream = [RemoteInputStream inputStreamWithURL:testURL];
    [inputStream open];
    
    NSUInteger maxLength = 16;
    uint8_t *buffer = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * maxLength);
    NSUInteger len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:maxLength];
    NSMutableData *streamingData = [NSMutableData new];
    
    while (len) {
        [streamingData appendBytes:buffer length:len];
        len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:maxLength];
    }
    
    free(buffer);
    
    XCTAssertTrue([normalData isEqualToData:streamingData]);
    
    [streamingData release];
}

@end
```

Comment: I agree re `NSURLSession` but I might be wary of `NSURLSessionDataTask`. I would be inclined to use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` (which avoids loading the asset in memory) and then do a buffered stream from the file. You really don’t want to block within a `NSURLSessionDataTask`.

Comment: And, in defense of bdash’s use of `NSURLConnection`, his answer predated `NSURLSession`. 